# How to filter a form with multi-Field in MS Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the code below in a click button event in MS Access 2013 form, whose datasource is from a query with the following fields “EnrNo, FirstName, LastName, and RegDate”.

The form has three text boxes and a command button:

1. txtKeyword
2. txtDateFrom
3. txtDateTo
4. cmdSearch

The click button (cmdSearch) in the form is intended to filter the query based on three criteria’s , which could be any of the two “EnrNo, FirstName, LastName” AND the range of the date(s) entered in the text box txtDateTo and cmdSearch

My code successfully filters only EnrNo. Please help me out... Thanks for your time.

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim strWhere As String                  'The criteria string.
Dim Where As String
Dim lngLen As Long                      'Length of the criteria string   to append to.
Const conJetDate = "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#"   'The format expected for dates in a JET query string.

'Text field example. Use quotes around the value in the string.
If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilter) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([EnrNo] = """ & Me.txtFilter & """) OR "
strWhere = strWhere & "([FirstName] = """ & Me.txtFilter & """) AND "
End If

'Date field example. Use the format string to add the # delimiters and get the right international format.
If Not IsNull(Me.txtFrom) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "([RegDate] >= " & Format(Me.txtFrom, conJetDate) & ") AND "
End If

'Another date field example. Use "less than the next day" since this field has times as well as dates.
If Not IsNull(Me.txtTo) Then   'Less than the next day.
strWhere = strWhere & "[RegDate] BETWEEN #" & Format(Me.txtFrom, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# AND #" & Format(Me.txtTo, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# "
End If

lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then     'Nah: there was nothing in the string.
    MsgBox "No criteria", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
Else                    'Yep: there is something there, so remove the "  AND " at the end.
    strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)
  'Debug.Print strWhere

Me.Filter = strWhere
Me.FilterOn = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: can you paste or debug.print your entire sql for the filter please once it's populated? be much easier to tell you what the issue is, i suspect it's stuff not being bracketed properly

Comment: It displays “Run-time error ‘3075’:
Syntax error in data in query expression ‘([EnrNo] = “MS-12/IT-004”) or ([FirstName] =  “MS-12/IT-004”) AND ([RegDate] >= #06/16/2014#) AND [RegDate] BETWEEN #06/16/2014# AND #09/23/2’

Answer (score 0):

It displays “Run-time error ‘3075’: Syntax error in data in query expression ‘([EnrNo] = “MS-12/IT-004”) or ([FirstName] = “MS-12/IT-004”) AND ([RegDate] >= #06/16/2014#) AND [RegDate] BETWEEN #06/16/2014# AND #09/23/2’ you have too  many operands here.

You will need to make it so your query's where statement is as follows;

```
(([EnrNo] = “MS-12/IT-004”) or ([FirstName] = “MS-12/IT-004”)) AND (([RegDate] >= #06/16/2014#) AND ([RegDate] BETWEEN #06/16/2014# AND #09/23/2014#))
```

Note the extra brackets I have placed in there. Logical operators (OR/AND) will return a value based upon TWO expressions. So for instance, a > b AND b > c returns true if BOTH conditions are true. a > b OR b > c returns true if EITHER statement is true.

If we write a statement like a > b and b > c or d > f we have too many conditions, so we need to nest them. So we would write it as (a > b AND b > c) OR d > f.

A good way to practice this is to create the query with the criteria manually in the query builder, then look at the bracketing placed on your conditions in the SQL view window of the query.

I hope this helps!